# Execution failed for JetifyTransform Flutter run

Tags: gradle, flutter, kotlin

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Failed to transform artifact 'x86_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-77c5812d48b861225ea629bd813ad502ddf2c89c)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}.
  >   Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Parth.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_debug\1.0.0-77c5812d48b861225ea629bd813ad502ddf2c89c\d987fc036069ac9d7bfec6a441e0c6ca9e6d8467\x86_debug-1.0.0-77c5812d48b861225ea629bd813ad502ddf2c89c.jar.
  >   Failed to transform 'C:\Users\Parth.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_debug\1.0.0-77c5812d48b861225ea629bd813ad502ddf2c89c\d987fc036069ac9d7bfec6a441e0c6ca9e6d8467\x86_debug-1.0.0-77c5812d48b861225ea629bd813ad502ddf2c89c.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: invalid distance code. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 5):

I had similar error and I added the chekReleaseBuilds false to the gradle file as indicated in the following:

```
lintOptions {
disable 'InvalidPackage'
checkReleaseBuilds false //added this line to the build.gradle under the 
/android/app/build.gradle 
}
```

This worked.